# Java could not print double side

Tags: java, printing

have an extracted piece of code to print double sided.

```
aset.add(new Copies(1));
aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
aset.add(Sides.DUPLEX);
aset.add(Sides.TWO_SIDED_LONG_EDGE);
printJob.print(printDocument, aset);
```

However all it comes out is single sided. My printer is able to print double sided with other applications. However, it just doesn't want to print double sided with Java. Any help is appreciated. thanks

Update: I ran a print on the doc flavor. This is the extract from my desired printer:

```
            PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
            for (PrintService ps: services) {
                System.out.println(ps + " supports :");
                DocFlavor[] flavors = ps.getSupportedDocFlavors();
                for (DocFlavor fl : flavors ){
                    System.out.println("\tFlavor:" + fl.toString());
                    System.out.println("\tMime Type:" + fl.getMimeType());
                    System.out.println("\tMediaType Type:" + fl.getMediaType());
                }

            }
```

output:

```
  Flavor:image/gif; class="[B"
  Mime Type:image/gif
  MediaType Type:image
  Flavor:image/gif; class="java.io.InputStream"
  Mime Type:image/gif
  MediaType Type:image
  Flavor:image/gif; class="java.net.URL"
  Mime Type:image/gif
  MediaType Type:image
  Flavor:image/jpeg; class="[B"
  Mime Type:image/jpeg
  MediaType Type:image
  Flavor:image/jpeg; class="java.io.InputStream"
  Mime Type:image/jpeg
  MediaType Type:image
  Flavor:image/jpeg; class="java.net.URL"
  Mime Type:image/jpeg
  MediaType Type:image
  Flavor:image/png; class="[B"
  Mime Type:image/png
  MediaType Type:image
  Flavor:image/png; class="java.io.InputStream"
  Mime Type:image/png
  MediaType Type:image
  Flavor:image/png; class="java.net.URL"
  Mime Type:image/png
  MediaType Type:image
  Flavor:application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class="java.awt.print.Pageable"
  Mime Type:application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref
  MediaType Type:application
  Flavor:application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class="java.awt.print.Printable"
  Mime Type:application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref
  MediaType Type:application
  Flavor:application/octet-stream; class="[B"
  Mime Type:application/octet-stream
  MediaType Type:application
  Flavor:application/octet-stream; class="java.net.URL"
  Mime Type:application/octet-stream
  MediaType Type:application
  Flavor:application/octet-stream; class="java.io.InputStream"
  Mime Type:application/octet-stream
  MediaType Type:application
```

Seems like all are either jpeg/gif/png image type. Is this is cause of the issue?
thanks

Comment: where's the rest of the code ? (example, what is asset, where do you get those Enums from ...)

Comment: hi, i got from the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/services.html

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on another printer? 
I've had a look at the example, if the problem is not with your printer, it could be a bug in JPS, log a bug: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/bugreports-140511.html

Comment: Hi Jan Vladimir Mostert. It is the same with other printers. I have printed out the doc flavor and updated in my post. thanks